# how do I render multiple gmap polylines quickly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I have some code that loops through an array of airline routes and airports placing markers at each airport and drawing polylines between them. The code works and is fine when I have 400 routes. When I expand it to the full ~3500ish routes it grinds to a halt for nearly a minute rendering. Is there any way I can speed this up?

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
var flightPath;
var flightPlanCoordinates;
$.each(routes, function(key, route) {
    flightPlanCoordinates = [];
    flightPlanCoordinates.push( markers[route.origincode].position );
    flightPlanCoordinates.push( markers[route.destinationcode].position );
    flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#004494',
        strokeOpacity: 0.2,
        strokeWeight: 1
    });
    flightPath.setMap(map); //commenting this line speeds things back up
    google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'mouseover', function (event) {
        this.setOptions({
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'mouseout', function (event) {
        this.setOptions({
            strokeOpacity: 0.2,
            strokeWeight: 1
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to request and decode the direction `json` data in background before the `MapsActivity` start. And your can also storage the decode LatLng in `SharedPreferencd`(eg: 1->(1.12,1.32), 2->(1.32, 2.52)) making it a flow-data instead of storage all date in an array which will cost you many resource and reduce the runnig-speed. At last, take LatLng data from `SharedPreferenced` and pain them.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: or you can setListener on users' operate, and render UI when it needed instead of render all of routes immediately, so much UI-change is a large task to UI-thread.

Comment: what i mean is that you can only change the UI in UI-thread, so when a big data come across, if you want to improve the speed , you should use streaming date instead of just an array.